# Bootstrap 5 cards should be display in a row, but they are displayed in a column when added a sidebar

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Why do bootstrap 5 cards, which arranged in a row, end up being displayed in a column when I added a sidebar? I started it using the method below, using that method, the cards displayed in a row, but when I added a sidebar, it displayed in a column.

```
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" 
    crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <p>Card Name</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <p>Card Name</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <p>Card Name</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
```

The cards, when I added the sidebar:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">

            <nav id="sidebar" class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block bg-light sidebar vh-100">
                <div class="position-sticky">
                    <ul class="nav flex-column">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="" class="nav-link active">Dashbaord</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="" class="nav-link">Page 1</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a href="" class="nav-link">Page 2</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

            
            <main class="col-md-3 col-lg-3 px-md-4">
                
                <div class="card my-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'Room_Content' room_type.id %}">
                            <p>Card Name</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card my-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'Room_Content' room_type.id %}">
                            <p>Card Name</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="card my-3">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'Room_Content' room_type.id %}">
                            <p>Card Name</p>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </main>

        </div>
    </div>
```

Are there any specific CSS classes or properties that can help me achieve the desired row layout even with with a sidebar in my web design.

Comment: The did not end up below each other simply because you added the sidebar - but because you significantly changed the structure of what was there already. You _had_ each of your cards in an individual `.col` element, inside a `.row` - and now they are all inside _one_ single `.col` element, your `main` element there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like the issue you're encountering is related to the Bootstrap grid system and the layout configuration. When you added the sidebar, the existing structure seems to have caused a change in the layout. To maintain the desired row layout even with the sidebar, you can modify the classes and structure as follows:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <nav id="sidebar" class="col-md-3 col-lg-2 d-md-block bg-light sidebar 
vh-100">
            <div class="position-sticky">
                <ul class="nav flex-column">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="" class="nav-link active">Dashboard</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="" class="nav-link">Page 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a href="" class="nav-link">Page 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <main class="col-md-9 col-lg-10 px-md-4"> <!-- Adjusted column width -->
            <div class="row"> <!-- Added a new row for the cards -->
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="card my-3">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 
 'Room_Content' room_type.id %}">
                                <p>Card Name</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col">
                    <div class="card my-3">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'Room_Content' room_type.id %}">
                                <p>Card Name</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col">
                    <div class="card my-3">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 
 'Room_Content' room_type.id %}">
                                <p>Card Name</p>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Sample Picture]

Comment: But the card are shown at below of sidebar, it means: the sidebar it doesn't take `100%` of it height.

Comment: I have also posted a picture for you that displays the sidebar on the left with 100% height and a card on its right side. However, if you don't want this, please elaborate on what you truly desire.